# .tex file becomes 0 kB when I change the file name

Tags: files

As I change the file name of the `.tex` file, the file suddenly becomes only 0 kB... Does anyone has the same experience here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which editor do you use, and how do you go about renaming the file in question?

Comment: I use the PCTEX. I just right clicked the abc000.tex and rename it into abc111.tex, and then the file size shown is 0K, and I can't compile it. Looks like everything is gone.

Comment: If you did the renaming in your file manager, that is very weird indeed. Changing names should not remove the content of a file. If you did the renaming via your editor, it might have a bug. I do feel however that this is not a LaTeX issue at its core. Does the problem also occur with files with different file extensions?

Comment: to moewe, no it only happened this one time, only to this tex file. I am trying to rewrite everything now... Do you know how to convert the .pdf file back to .tex file?

Comment: There are tools like PDFtotext which may aid you in extracting the text from the PDF. Also Tools like Acrobat Pro may be helpful.